# Should a class perform bounds checking when you are after performance

Tags: c++, language-agnostic

Say I have a triangle class, defined something like

```
class Triangle{
vertex3D vertexs[3];
public:
vertex* GetVertex(int vertexNumber);
}
```

now for most normal applications its fairly obvious that `GetVertex` should ensure that `vertexNumber` is a valid index before trying to return the vertex pointer. I would say that normally it can return NULL if `vertexNumber` is not valid, but that's not really what I am asking about.

In a game situation, checking if `vertexNumber` is valid all the time could take up a fair bit of time, it would be quicker for `GetVertex` to assume that only valid values will be passed in.

So would it be acceptable for triangle to basically throw caution to the wind in the name of a slight performance boost?

If I do go for a bounds checking in debug but not release, how can I automate this so that I don't have to edit the code? Some sort of compile time switch or something? would using `#ifdef debug` sort of stuff work? where can I find more about this?

Comment: I'd use an debug assertion for the debug build, and go for speed in release.

Comment: Could you run a performance test on your final application use case and see if it really makes a significant difference?  If the expected precondition was well documented it would be reasonable to me.

Comment: Yes, #ifdef around your check is the way you do it in C.  In C++ you can have two accessor methods with #ifdef ... #else ... #endif

Comment: Concerning your edit, on some platforms, the `assert` macro from `<cassert>` is a no-op in release builds. If that's not the case on your platform, you can easily write your own `assert` macro and `#define assert(x, y) /* nothing */` in release builds.  You only need to test `#ifdef DEBUG` once:  wherever you define your `assert` macro (or whatever you choose to call it; I wouldn't define your own macro named `assert` since that name is used by the standard library's `assert` macro).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely check the bounds in a debug build.

If you're sure that your code is correct (so, you've had a code review and you've tested it extensively) then it is fine to leave out bounds checks in a release build for the sake of performance.

If you are going to test the bounds in a debug build but not in a release build then you should probably use an assert in the debug build.  asserts should be used to verify things that are always true.  If you are not checking bounds inside of the function and your code is correct, then the value should never be out of bounds.

Answer (score 4):

Code it with the check in place.  When you have a running program, you can profile it and find out what places you might make changes that are actually going to help performance.  Those places may not be where you expected at all.

Comment: This is the best suggestion I've seen.  Premature optimization is the bane of code readability and maintainability.  It's easier to refactor readable code for performance than to maintain cryptic code that may or may not improve performance because no one's profiled it.

Answer (score 3):

If `vertexNumber` is never a value which comes directly from external input, then I believe that you can assume that it is always valid - i.e. you acknowledge the existence of a *contract* saying that "this function will behave correctly when vertexNumber is either 0, 1 or 2". Then the class itself can be understood as "correct and safe" in terms of code correctness and you only need to worry about the clients (users of this class) using it in the correct way - i.e. not breaking the contract.

Usually perfect tool for that is using assert() inside the class methods to check if the contract is satisfied. Then, you'll have a runtime check in the `debug` build and no checks at all in the `release` build.

Answer (score 2):

If that class is in application code (code that is only used in one application), ***measure*** whether the performance gain is relevant and then decide whether to remove he checks in Release mode. (Leave them in for Debug mode.)

If that class is in library code, it's a design decision. Do you want your class to be ***as safe as possible*** or ***as fast as possible***? Seeing that this is graphics code, you probably want the latter. (This also became popular with the STL, which aims for speed.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think not doing bounds checking at all is a good approach.
If you care about performance in this case at least use `assert` which can be disabled in release configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> ..fair bit of time
>   ..slight performance boost

You have to decide which is true first. I'd say write both versions, and measure the perf differences first. Or even better, write the version with the checks, measure, and decide if the perf is below your expectations/needs. If it is, then start optimizing. I suppose at this point, removing bounds-check for the sake of performance (if it's provably more performant, enough to contribute significantly) might become an easier, more informed choice.

And if you decide to remove bounds check, then design by contract :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making `Triangle` an object?  It looks like a simple data holder.  It is not used polymorphically.  It does not have any behavior.  It is not an object.  Let it be a simple POD struct with public data, *especially* if you are worried about performance.

This has the added bonus that when a caller tries to use `vertexNumber := 0xdeadbeef`, the access violation happens in the faulty caller trying to use the array publicly, not in a bug-free helper shim.  This may not mean much in the debug environment, but when you get a crashdump report that doesn't include a complete backtrace, it's an issue.

Props to [jalf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33213/jalf) for [an in-depth <strike>rant</strike> discussion I can link](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/11/good-design-oop/).

Comment: Because I will be wanting to do things such as intersection testing and other functions on. sure I could just have a static function that takes two triangles and checks if they are intersecting, but why not do it as a member function of triangle that checks if this triangle intersects with a passed in one?

Comment: Still not hearing any need for private data completely exposed through accessors.

Comment: I see what you are saying their. but that is a different discussion altogether

Answer (score 1):

Design by contract , Eiffel and the book "Object Oriented software construction, Myer" would say that you should define checks for out of bound issues like this as assertions that you can compile out of the final product.  The assertions define the mathematical certainty of the complete system.